# Перенес сайт на WP на локальный сервер

Tags: php, wordpress

Перенес сайт на WP  на локальный сервер и тут выскочила такая ошибка:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for limit_words() in Z:\home\law\www\wp-content\themes\law\functions.php on line 207
```

такая функция находиться в 207 строке:

```
add_action( 'init', 'limit_words' );
function limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
    $words = explode(" ",$string);
    return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, подскажите куда копать?)

Answer (score 4):

Функция `limit_words()` принимает два аргумента. Вот второй - `$word_limit` не передается. В строке 207 записана сама функция. А копать нужно там, где она вызывается.

Comment: а есть быстрый способ узнать где функция эта вызывается?)

Comment: в любой IDE, где есть поддержка Wordpress. Например, PHPStorm или Netbeans, У них есть плагины для разработки под Wordpress.

Comment: в сайблайме есть такое?))

Comment: Нет. В текстовых редакторах такого нет. Нужна именно IDE.